# Facebook Test User Login URL - Doesn't work after clearing cache/cookies

Tags: ios, safari, mobile-safari, facebook-test-users

I have a test users page for my site which loads a simple grid of 4 buttons, which, when clicked, launch their associated Facebook test user login_url. I'm obtaining these via the PHP SDK and they work great...

Except when the cookies are cleared in Safari (mobile and desktop)... In this case, the test user login_url takes me to a Facebook login page where I'm prompted to login.

If I clear cookies and visit the plain old www.facebook.com homepage first and then navigate to my site, it works fine.

I understand that the 3rd party cookie setting would prevent me from loading this login_url successfully in an iFrame, but I don't understand why it doesn't work when I actually try to follow the link.

Is this a bug? Are Facebook test users a rather unpolished developer feature?

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: I work for Facebook, but I am not on the Platform team, so my knowledge on this topic isn't that much more than a regular developer.

The `login_url` mechanism is not a full blown secure login mechanism. I would venture to guess that it switches the identity of the currently logged in user from the regular user to the test user. However, if there is no currently logged in user, it can't switch the identity, and therefore needs to ask you to login.

However, test users do have a user ID and password (which were returned as a response to the create API) that you could use to go through the standard Facebook login procedure. Note though that as far as I know, currently there is no automated method of loggin a user using the user ID/password - they are intended for manual logging in scenarios.

Comment: I dont think this is the case, because the login_url parameter works great if I simply visit www.facebook.com before using my button (no logging in whatsoever. Just simply visiting www.facebook.com and accepting the cookie). In this case, there is no identity switching going on.

Comment: Well, then apparently it needs some certain cookie value to be set on facebook.com for these login URLs to work. It would not call this a “bug” per se, because these login URLs are for testing purposes only (and can only be used once anyway, after that you’ll have to get a _new_ login URL) …

Comment: I'll check with the Platform team to see what's going on. If the `login_url` does work only by visiting facebook.com but no loggin in actual user, it is an odd behavior. Would you mind shooting me a more detailed email with maybe some repro steps of what exactly you're doing at my @fb.com email? (Hint - it's the same as my personal one here in my profile)

Comment: @Franci - Do you know if this is a bug or not?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't gotten a chance to follow up on this yet. :-( It was a bit crazy here at work...